# MAXScript: How to find duplicate texturemap names and rename this via maxscript?

Tags: rename, maxscript

I have a large 3ds max scene that uses a huge number of texturemap (bitmap, mix, composite, noise etc. etc.), but many different texturemap have the same name, although they are different texturemap (NOT **instances**). How can I find texturemap with duplicate names and assign a new name to this?
I tried different methods using *uniqueName* and *assignNewName*, but it didn’t give the desired result - some texturemaps are renamed repeatedly and still have the same new names, although they are different texturemaps or not renamed at all. Is there any quick and reliable way to do this?

Comment: This script helps you to find textures with same name and place them to material editor https://3d-kstudio.com/product/trackscripts/#InstanceMatByName

Comment: @track, Thanks, but your link is not at all what I need. Read my question carefully.

Comment: Using this script you can place textures in the Material Editor and rename them. For writing a custom script use the textureMap.Classes for enumerating and getclassInstances method

Answer (score 0):

You could use getClassInstances and loop through them... An example for rename all bitmaps to the filename might be:

```
for mapToRename in ( getClassInstances Bitmaptexture ) do 
(
 mapToRename.name = getfilenamefile mapToRename.filename
 format ">%\n" mapToRename.name  
)
```

for mix, maybe include the name of the two inputs ( you'll probably want to trap to ensure .map1 and .map2 are valid )

```
for mixToRename in ( getClassInstances Mix) do 
(
 mixToRename.name = ( "MIX : " + mixToRename.map1.name + " x "+ mixToRename.map2.name )
 format ">%\n" mixToRename.name  
)
```

cheers